# retrieving props from mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a session handler, for all the components where i need to determine if a user is logged in. however if i add a console.log(authUser) in `withAuthentication` it returns a user, but however not in the `SideBar`. Here it always be `null`. What am i doing wrong?

**withAuthentication**

```
const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    const { onSetAuthUser } = this.props;

    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
        ? onSetAuthUser(authUser)
        : onSetAuthUser(null);

    });
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <Component />
    );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSetAuthUser: (authUser) => dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER_SET', authUser }),
});

return connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WithAuthentication);
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);


}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="app">
    <SideBar />
        <div>
        <Navigation/>

        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={routes.LANDING}  component={() => <LandingPage />} />

            <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
}

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

**SideBar**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    sideBarOpen: false
};



class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props.authUser);
        console.log(props)
        this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };

    }

    render() {
        const {
            sideBarOpen,
            authUser
        } = this.state;

        const {
            children,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            {authUSer ?
            'authed' :
            'not authed'
            }

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authUser: state.sessionState.authUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SideBar);
```

**reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    authUser: null,
};

const applySetAuthUser = (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    authUser: action.authUser
});


function sessionReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case 'AUTH_USER_SET' : {
        return applySetAuthUser(state, action);
    }
    default : return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  sessionState: sessionReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Can you share your reducer code? BTW, you have a typo in return ({ authUSer...

Comment: @Faheem i have added reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `mapStateToProps` setup

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authUser: state.sessionState.authUser
});
```

You need to get `authUser` from component `props` not from component `state`.

So your code should be `const authUser = this.props.authUser`.

Or your way `const {authUser} = this.props`

Comment: isnt that what i'm trying in `SideBar` in the constructor with `console.log(props)`

Comment: @PeterPik he is right. In the sidebar, you are destructuring authUser from this.state. You should instead use this.props.